# Should I update LiveData to Flow in domain/data layers?

Tags: android, android-livedata, coroutine

I'm working on a big project that uses LiveData on any layer. We only use room to store a two small entities, all of the data is fetched from a service, don't use any cache. Also we don't use coroutines, all is done with LiveData. This project is already in the store (released in 2017) so it is a big stable project.

I was looking for latest library updates and in many places uses Flow in domain/data layers and then in ViewModel switches to LiveData.

Should we add coroutines and replace LiveData to Flow in domain/data layers?

Comment: If your project is in java then you have nothing to do with coroutines and flow, otherwise using flow and coroutines is like having some superpower

Comment: As @RaBaKa78 said, it would be good to explore `Coroutines` / `Flow` + `LiveData` only if you are migrating to `Kotlin`.

Comment: The project is already 100% Kotlin

Comment: Then @JavierCancio you should try it, there are some concepts to tackle first, but you will eventually be a master if you spend time.